# Scala: Best Way to Avoid Multiple time doing same operation in different Match-case

Tags: scala

I want to find the minimum of all the values in a row of a table (there might be null values, the columns might be of different types-Int, Long, Double, Boolean).

The return type of the function depends on the input columns, if all are Int then the return type should be Int. If mix of different types, then double, etc.

I have the knowledge of what the returnType would be.

Method is like:

```
 def findMin(args: List[Any]): Any =
```

One possible solution could be:

```
returnType match {
  case IntType =>
     minValInt = Int.Min
     for(args){
        check for not null 
        for(arg <- args) {
          temp: Int  = arg match {
             case x: Int => x
             case x: Boolean => convert to Int              
          }
        minValInt = min(minValInt, temp)
        return minValInt

  case LongType =>
     minValLong = Long.Min
     for(args){
       check for not null -> minValLong = min(minValLong, arg) (some restrictions while using the arg value directly)
     }
     return minValLong

  case DoubleType =>
     minValDouble = Double.Min
     for(arg <- args){
       check for not null 
       temp: Double = arg match {
          case x: Int => convert to double 
          case x: Long => convert to double (some restrictions while converting)
          case x: Double => x
          case x: Boolean => convert to double
       }
       minValDouble = min(minValDouble, temp)
     }
     return minValDouble
}
```

Can this be done in single match-case or something better "more neatly"?

Comment: You can't have a single function returning different types depending on its parameters, so it's going to return Any so somewhere you're going to have a cast. All a bit of a mess. What's the use-case? What will you use the minimum value returned for?

Comment: @ArchetypalPaul sure you can. It's called a generic ;) (or whatever the fancy name that thing has in scala).

Comment: @Dima - sure you cannot. Generics is about type calculation at compile time based on parameter TYPES. What this question is about is calculating the return type at runtime based on dynamically recognized value types.

Comment: @Det, I am just saying that the statement "You can't have a single function returning different types depending on its parameters" from the previous comment is wrong. Are we in agreement on that? Your statement isn't much better either :) First, you have misread the question: the OP says, that he _knows_ what the return type should be. Second, to see how you are wrong, simply consider this function: `def identity[T](x: T) = x` it's return type  is different, depending on the parameter. This is just the simplest example, of course, you can do much fancier things, using manifests and implicits.

Comment: As "Any" is the superset of all the types in Scala. So, returning different types depending on parameters works.

Comment: "Are we in agreement on that? " Only if you include type parameters, which wasn't what I meant.

Comment: @VP, no,, it returns the single type `Any`. Which can of course have subtypes.

Comment: "first, you have misread the question: the OP says, that he knows what the return type should be." At runtime, it seems since it takes a parameter "returnType". If the type is statically known at  the call site, then yes, generics  or typeclasses can do the job. So @VP, we need more information.

Comment: @Dima Your identity function is exactly the example for what I've written. The actual type of type parameter T is calculated at compile time based on the calling context.

Comment: @Det, you mean, it's a _counterexample_ to what you you have written, right? That function's return type depends on its parameter, and you said that it was impossible (you did not write anything about compile time, but, if you did, that would notale your statement exactly correct either).

Comment: @Dima No, you are still not understanding what I meant. (And I _did_ write about compile time!) Considering your _identity_: `val a:Int = 5; val c:Any = a; val z:Int = identity(c)` does not compile although the passed _value_ (the parameter 5) itsself has the correct type. T is statically calculated to be Any because of the parameter's static type in the call context, and so is the return type! But indeed OP asked about `def fixed(x:Any):Any = x match { case i:Int => i.toInt ; ....}` with `val y:Int = fixed(a)` this doesn't work either, as the return type is not based on runtime value of x.

Comment: @Det where do you see him assigning the result to an `Int` variable?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
list.flatMap(x => Option(x)).minBy { 
   case n: Number => n.doubleValue
   case true => 1.0
   case false => 0.0
}(Ordering.Double)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside my lack of imagination regarding the use case, you already defined the function type to be List [Any] -> Any in your question.

So you are telling the compiler effectively nothing about what to expect and lose the advantage of having a static type system.

Please note that functional programming with static types is about defining the input domain and map it to the output domain at compile time.
So a function returning an Int is not identical to a function returning a Long or one returning a Double. So either they are different functions or you define the output domain to be of the common super type of all possible return types, losing specific information on the way.

Regarding the shown code it seems that the return type is any of Int, Long, Double depending on the maximum precision needed to return the min value.

As an Int fits in a Long and both fit in a Double,  why not declare Double as the guaranteed maximum precision return type?

Thus the function would be of type List[Any] -> Double, making the rest of the program specific at compile time an thus type safe?

Comment: In that case will miss the precision say:
9223372036854775807,9223372036854775800,9223372036854775801

Min: 9223372036854775800
But in case of double: 9223372036854775801 even will pass.

Comment: Exact use-case is at last the type of return-value has also to be displayed. So, if I am trying to find min(long, long), then I would like the result to be in long. First I had converted everything into double and then found the above testcase which passed even after giving wrong expected value.